# Powershell script failing in Octopus

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a powershell script in my octopus process to run a powershell script on a server. When I run the script on the server itself it runs fine. When I try to incorporate the script in the octopus deploy process it just hangs and does not run. It gets as far as line 8 and just hangs.

Is there something on line 8 that I am not seeing. The line that starts with $process

```
Write-Host "Executing Protractor cmdline: & "$TestProtractorPathAndName" 
$TestProtractorArgs "
if (test-path $TestProtractorResultPath) {Remove-Item –path 
"$TestProtractorResultPath" –recurse}
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -path "$TestProtractorResultPath"
$args = "$TestProtractorArgs" 
Write-Host "Run Protractor scripts"
Write-Host $TestProtractorResultFile
Write-Host $TestProtractorResultFileLabel
$process = Start-Process "$TestProtractorPathAndName" $args -Wait - 
PassThru
Write-Host 'Exit code = $($process.ExitCode)'
New-OctopusArtifact -Path "$TestProtractorResultFile" -Name 
"$TestProtractorResultFileLabel"
if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0){
  Write-Host "Protractor cmdline complete"
} else {
  Write-Error "Protractor cmdline failed"
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is broken due to incorrectly wrapped lines. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it still exposes the problem you're trying to analyze, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code. Include all errors you're getting from *that* code. We cannot help you when the code you're showing us has additional problems that are not present in your original code.

Comment: It is hard to guess what the problem is. Might be the permissions/access level for the user under which tentacle is running. Would need more details. By the way, have you looked into a verbose output from Octopus run? Might give some hints.

Comment: @hankey39 Check the user account used by Tentacle service, In most cases that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is potentially a permissions issue - a difference in permissions between the interactive account that can run the script in person on the machine, and the tentacle that is installed and running as a service on the machine.

The best way to iron out these issues is to simulate running your script as a tentacle. This can easily be achieved in Octopus Deploy using the **Script Console** feature.

[image]

Here you can write your PowerShell script and execute it on a tentacle, rather than running it using an interactive session on the deployment target - it will give you a much clearer picture when trying to troubleshoot issues like this.

[image]

Hope this helps